# permalink and $_GET

Tags: links, post-type

i create a new post-type called servizi.
I customize the permalink for this structure:
/%post_id%/%postname%/
But there are a different width post link .
For example the post link is  www.mysite.it/site-wp/25/postname/ and the servizi's link is www.mysite.it/site-wp/servizi/postname/.
I dont't understand what is the trouble .

In details page how can take the post_id variable?
I use $_GET or i customize my function.php with special function?

Someone can i help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason you are adding the post_id to the URL because you are you trying to access the post_id variable in the template? You can do so much more easily by accessing it in the Loop of your template file

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        // Two ways to get the Post ID //
        echo $post -> ID; 
        echo get_the_ID();
    endwhile; ?>
endif; 
?>
```